# How many combinations when choosing from partitioned subsets and limiting overlap?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have 100 numbered balls and I'm selecting combinations of 6, I have N choose K total combinations (1,192,052,400). I want to partition the 100 balls into 10 (M) subsets of 10, and then still choose 6, however I limit myself to only choosing 1 element from any of the 10 partitions.

```
N = the # of balls
K = the size of chosen subsets
M = number of partitions
L = N / M, the number of balls per partition
```

My thought was that I would basically just make M choose M to get the partitions I would be choosing an element from and then making (N/M) choose 1 independent decisions K times. What I came up with for a formula is:

$${M \choose K}{L \choose 1}^K$$

This is making the assumption that M > K. Breaking it down using my original numbers, where N = 100, K = 6, M = 10, and L = 10 gives me: 210 * 1,000,000, or 210,000,000 combinations. Is this correct?

A second aspect, is that I want to limit the overlap between two subsets to say that at most I want 50% of the elements to be shared between the other K item subsets. So, using my numbers above, out of the 6 out of 100 chosen, at most only 3 will be shared with any other single subset. How do I calculate the number of combinations for both 100 choose 6 case and where I've partitioned the set into groups of 10 items?

Sorry if this is confusing, I don't know the correct terminology and this is not my area of expertise so I'm a bit out of my element :)

Comment: Your formulation of the first problem is clear and the answer is correct.  What is not clear is the paragraph that begins "A second aspect..."

Comment: I want to limit the number of combinations to only subsets which share at most K/2 elements. I want to know how to calculate for both the pure N choose K and the second formula. Does that help?